# Maintaining HTML page after form submission?

Tags: html, ajax

I'm wondering if it is possible to keep an HTML page in view, or at least part of it after a form submit button is press.  I was planning on having the top of the page with log-in fields and I wanted the top of the page to stay after hitting the submit button, so authentication would be processed, and a new bottom of the page is displayed.  Is this possible?

Comment: Asynchronous Javascript (AJAX) is probably the most modern approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use jQuery and AJAX to do this. when the AJAX request has been sent, you hide the bottom section and then, on completion, the new bottom section is loaded. have a look into it. if you need a code sample i'll be happy to supply some.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use ajax.  Ajax allows you to submit the form while not actually leaving the page at all.. It's basically javascript loading another page (and in this case with the form variables necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible. You must send the FORM as AJAX request. Now you can use one of the following frameworks:

1. JQuery
2. Prototype
3. ExtJS

My personal recommendation is JQuery (but you can check others). Also is the possibility of implement AJAX from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible. try to use JQuery and AJAX.

Refer to this code:

```
$(function(){
   $('#loginForm').submit(function(){
       $.post("includes/login_process.php", {userName: $("#txtUsername").val(), password: $("#txtPassword").val()}, function(response){
           alert(response);
     });
   });
});
```